# count of the maximum number of paths in a graph

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-theory, depth-first-search

Have a graph - V, E = V^2,

Now, I have written a DFS algo which visits all paths in a graph, but i am not able to find its time complexity because i dont know the count of the maximum number of paths in a graph. Please can some one tell me the count of the maximum number of paths in a graph [path between one vertex to all vertices for a directed graph] or the time complexity of this code -

```
unordered_map<int , int> minTime;
vector<vector<pair<int,int>>> adjList;
vector<int> visited;

   void dfs(int v, int currPathLength){

    visited[v] = true;
    
    if(currPathLength < minTime[v])
    {
        minTime[v] = currPathLength;
    }

    for(auto& x : adjList[v])
    {
        
        if(!visited[x.first])
        {
            currPathLength += x.second;
            dfs(x.first, currPathLength);
            currPathLength -= x.second;
            visited[x.first] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Paths between two specific vertices?  Paths between a specific vertex and every other?  Paths between every possible pair of vertices?

Comment: Directed or undirected graph?

Comment: path between one vertex to all vertices, and then directed

Comment: Edit your question.  Do not bury important clarifications in comments.

Answer (score 1):

To find all the paths between a specified pair of vertices in a directed graph, apply Yen's algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm

Note:  these are a number of errors in the wikipedia article.  Here is the psuedo-code for a tested implementation of Yen's algorithm https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/All-Paths#algorithm

This gives you the number of distinct paths between one pair of vertices.  You will need to run it multiple times if you realyl want to find ALL the paths in your graph.

If your graph is undirected, you will have to convert it to directed by adding a back edge for every edge that does not already have one.

Comment: whats the time complexity of yen's, also can you help me with time complexity of code i posted in question please

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm#Time_complexity